# maven-release-plugin: Perform fails with 'working directory "...workspace\target\checkout\workspace" does not exist!'

Tags: hudson, version-control, maven, maven-release-plugin

I have maven project that fails when release:perform is called, though release;prepare works as expected.

I have found the bug report (below) which certainly seems to resemble the issue I have but not entirely sure I understand the problem:
[MRELEASE516](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-516)

The last few lines of output I get:

```
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "p4 -d E:\hudson\jobs\myHudsonJob\workspace\target\checkout -p 1.1.1.1:1111: client -d myProjectWorkspace-MavenSCM-E:\hudson\jobs\myHudsonJob\workspace\target\checkout"
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
[WARNING] Base directory is a file. Using base directory as POM location.
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error executing Maven.

Working directory "E:\hudson\jobs\myHudsonJob\workspace\target\checkout\workspace" does not exist!
```

From reading the bug report the possible cause of the error is related to my modules' structure, I've tried to outline it below:

```
/workspace
|
|+ pom.xml (root pom whose parent is the build pom, 
|           calling release:perform on this pom)
|           [Modules: moduleA and moduleB]
|
|- moduleA
   |+ pom.xml (parent is also build pom)
   |+ build/pom.xml (the build pom - no custom parent)
|- moduleB
   |+ pom.xml (parent is build pom)
```

It seems that the root pom should be in some common directory inside 'workspace' from the error but tried that and doesn't work, nor make sense as to why I need it.

What does the warning *Base directory is a file* want me to do instead?! It then figures that the base directory is *workspace* which then means the working directory is not found...any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Having checked the SCM configuration it all looks ok to me...in each module and the root pom I have:

```
<scm>
<connection>
    scm:perforce:1.1.1.1:1111://rootToDirectoryContainingRelevantPom
</connection>
<developerConnection>
    scm:perforce:1.1.1.1:1111://rootToDirectoryContainingRelevantPom
</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Maybe I have hit [MRELEASE-261](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-261?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=205043#action_205043)?

Comment: Without the content of your poms its difficult to say something and to analyze the problem. On the other hand why do you have such kind of structure (parent pom in deeper levels?) Does moduleA has a modules section for build ?

Comment: I think the reason the parent of other poms is in a deeper level is because our project started off as just moduleA and has grown since then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by using a newer version of the release plugin. The Maven [super pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM) has a dependency on v2.0 of the release plugin defined. If you don't override this then that the version will be used.
You can specify a newer version when you run the plugin

```
  mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.1:perform
```

Or you can override the dependency version in your pom

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're facing [MRELEASE-516](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-516) (which is about `release:prepare`). However, I wonder if you have correct `<scm>` informations in each POM. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Near the bottom of the bug report he goes on to explain what happens if he runs release:perform and gets exactly the same error...although I guess you're right, the majority of the report talks about prepare. Will double check scm details now...thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Working directory "E:\hudson\jobs\myHudsonJob\workspace\target\checkout\workspace" does not exist!
```

I just saw the above line in your log. It looks like you have some screwy path setting somewhere. Do you overwrite the Workspace somewhere? Check your configuration and try to eliminate as much as possible the optional settings.

Comment: No, I don't override the workspace, I use the default which appears to be target/checkout but since maven thinks I have a root directory and then that must be 'workspace' it decides to checkout under workspace as well...workspace is just the default directory hudson uses as my Perforce workspace. Cheers

Comment: As an additional note; if I didn't make it clear, the correct directory it should be using is "E:\hudson\jobs\myHudsonJob\workspace\target\checkout" since in this directory once it has failed are modules I need to package up

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same symptoms turned out to be a result of a bug in maven-release-plugin:2.2.1. See [MRELEASE-705](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-705).

So to get rid of the error, I've got to put this into the parent pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was occurring for us

```
Working directory E:\Data\myproject\target\checkout does not exist!
```

We're in the middle of a large transition of server tools and maven's `release:prepare` appeared to be failing silently, claiming the tags and version number changes had been pushed without error.  However, after some research, these things had only been committed to the local git repository, not pushed - even though the `release:prepare` was executing commands to perform a push but never reported a failure -- even with the maven `-e` and `-X` command line parameters.

We're using Maven 3.3.9, maven release plugin 2.5.3, and git client 2.9.2.

Our end solution was to **add** a (or correct the, as your case may be) definition in maven's `~\.m2\settings.xml` file for our git server (origin master) including username and password with privileges for pushing tags (as well as pushing to master).  The `id` in the server definition for the git server needed to be the git server's hostname:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>git-server</id>
    <username>dan</username>
    <password>changeit</password>
  </server>
<servers>
```

With this update, the tag completes on the server and the checkout occurred successfully.